# Lost ability to insert inline images in Gmail

Tags: gmail, images

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [I can’t get in inline image in gmail](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/9513/i-cant-get-in-inline-image-in-gmail)

In trying to get inline images to work, I've somehow lost the "insert image" icon, and I don't know how to find it again.

It's 4:59am, and I'm very tired of writing this one e-mail and trying to get one picture inline with the text.  I'm going to bed now.  I hope the computer elves come and fix it while I'm sleeping.

Answer (score 2):

Part of my answer to your original question:

If you do have the labs option for "Inserting Images" and you've enabled it but you still don't see the option in the Rich Text editor make sure you don't have "Offline" support enabled. It will not work with this. If you do, remove the "Inserting Images," disable "Offline Support" then re-enable "Inserting Images" and you should be good to go.